# How do I add artisan to my Package and Improve my Laravel Package Development Workflow?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I am trying to create Laravel packages and I would like access to artisan so that I can create controllers, models, and so on.. I remember there being a laravel package for Laravel Package Development but I can't for the life of me remember. I am trying to improve my workflow, how can I add something like artisan to my package development? Can it be done?

P.S. I don't want to add artisan commands I want to use the CLI tool from my package. Is this possible?

Comment: Yeah its possible, laravel artisan behind the scenes uses symfony console input interface, you could use it easily in your case. https://api.symfony.com/2.8/Symfony/Component/Console/Input/InputInterface.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think 'Laravel Packager' is something you are looking for you can find more about this here

https://github.com/Jeroen-G/laravel-packager/blob/master/readme.md

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for thank you so much!